# Mutt autoedit option without edit_headers

Tags: vim, mutt

In order to skip the addressee and subject prompts before editing a message, one must set both `autoedit` and `edit_headers`.  But setting the latter puts the header into the edit buffer.  Is it not possible to skip the prompt without having the header in the buffer?
I have a rather long header, and no need to edit it along with the message.

Alternatively, is there a way to exclude a particular header items from the
edit buffer?

PS.  The reasons I do not want to give the addressee and subject first 
are

1. I do not want to worry about accidentally sending the message prematurely;
2. It may be easier to think of a suitable subject line after the message has been written.

I'm using Vim as my editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the filetype plugin for mails in `vim`:

Create the file `$HOME/.vim/ftplugin/mail.vim` with the single line

```
set foldmethod=manual
1,/^$/-1fold
norm }
```

This will cause the the above commands to be executed every time the mail filetype plugin loads, which it does when you're editing a mail message.

The commands will create a fold over the headers (everything from the start of the file to the first empty line) and collapse them into a single line. The `norm }` command will simply place you on the first line of the body of the message (you may alternatively want to use `/^-- /-1` instead to place the cursor on the last line of the message, before the signature).

To open the fold, step over it and type `zo`.  To close it, step over it and type `zc`.

This is assuming that you have `autoedit` and `edit_headers` set in `mutt` already.

---

`vim` with a new message, headers folded:

```
+--  8 lines: From: Myself <my.name@example.com>-------
hello

--
my signature here
```

With the headers unfolded:

```
From: Myself <my.name@example.com>
To:
Cc:
Bcc:
Subject:
Reply-To:
Organization: blipp blopp beep beep

hello

--
my signature here
```

Comment: It looks as if this puts `<<<` and `>>>` into the header.

Comment: @Toothrot Huh? "It works for me"... does it _actually_ insert that into the header, or does it just look like it?

Comment: It does do that.  Maybe because I have `set foldmarker=<<<,>>>` and `set foldmethod=marker`.

Comment: @Toothrot What version of `vim` are you using? I have 8.0 here (8.0.1589 to be more precise).

Comment: @Toothrot Ah, yes, that would explain it. Possibly.

Comment: Yeah, just had to put `set foldmethod=manual` in mail.vim.

Comment: @Toothrot Notice that I changed the `fold` command slightly. You will want to fold the first empty line too so that you don't accidentally write the message on it (which would mess up the mail format).

Comment: Mutt will insert the empty line.  Did you have `1,/^$/-1fold` before?  I'll use that and end with `norm G`. Thanks!